# log4net: Is there an easy way to use HTTP POST to send error logs to a URI?

Tags: http, post, log4net, appender

I'm pretty new to Log4Net (I used log4j), and I'm wondering the best strategy for sending error logs (on Error or Fatal Error) to a URI. The server's already set up and listening.

I was going to risk re-inventing the wheel and extend the AppenderSkeleton class to create a POSTAppender. Is there any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not an easier way to do it.  Extending `AppenderSkeleton` is fairly easy and I'd recommend trying your hand at it.  There's only one method you're required to override, `Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)`.

For your specific Error or Fatal requirements, you could use a `threshold` setting or a `Filter` in your log4net configuration.

For reference, there is a [list of built-in appenders for log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.html).

Comment: I thought maybe there was an appender I was missing, because I couldn't find any! Thank you for your answer :)